# SDK2: Example of Rally.ui.chart using datetime for x Axis?

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

Do you have any examples of the new Rally.ui.chart.Chart using datetime for the x Axis?  The examples in the documentation don't seem to use the XAxis to set labels, and I think a datetime example would be very instructive.

Comment: We are still working on releasing our first App that uses that component. Many times the SDK will have a component released in it that was created but not yet used in our examples or catalog Apps. 

We will be sure to share some examples as soon as we have them ready.